# Anchor tags and browser history with Jquery filter function

Tags: jquery, tags, anchor, hashchange

I'm working on a page with a navigation that filters products on the page. I've used the jQuery hashchange to add and remove a current state to the nav links when the links are clicked and when the browser back button is pressed. The filter() function however only works when the nav links are clicked, I would like to implement the filter function when the browser back button is clicked or if the url includes the anchor tag at the end.

Here's the link to the page:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20585252/test/index.htm

And here's the section of the Jquery that is relevent:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).hashchange( function(){
var hash = location.hash;

$('#nav a').each(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'current' );
});
})

$(window).hashchange();
filter();

});


function filter() {

    $('ul#nav a').click(function() {


    var filterVal = $(this).attr('rel');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul.product li.hidden').show().removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('ul.product li').hide().each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

});


}
```

A point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, slightly tricky but I think that with a mild refactoring of the code and a little jiggery-pokery, you should be able to trigger the filter from the hashchange handler.

The code below is untested and may not be quite right but should provide a way ahead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');//remove # for cross-browser compatibility
        $('#nav a').each(function(){
            var that = $(this);
            //that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'current' );
            if(that.attr('href') === hash) {
                that.addClass('current');
                filter.call(that);//call filter with '$(this)' as the context
            }
            else {
                that.removeClass('current');
            }
        });
    });
    function filter() {
        //Note: 'this' is a jquery object due to the way in which filter is called (in two places).
        var filterVal = this.attr('rel');
        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul.product li.hidden').show().removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('ul.product li').hide().each(function() {
                if(!this.hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    this.hide().addClass('hidden');
                }
                else {
                    this.show().removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $('ul#nav').on('click', 'a', function(){
        filter.call($(this));
    });
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I needed to tweak it slightly as the .replace('#',''); broke the hashchange function so I'll have to figure out a way to make it cross-browser friendly but other than that this was exactly what I was after. Much apreciated

Comment: If removing the `#` breaks it, then you need to prepend a `#` if it's not already present. Something like: `hash = (location.hash.match(/^#/)) ? location.hash : ('#'+location.hash);`